# Traducción de aviso de preguntas duplicadas

Tags: soporte, estado-completado, traducciones

Revisando preguntas me he encontrado una duplicada y he observado que hay un mensaje que necesita ser traducido.

He buscado por meta y no he encontrado otra pregunta igual al respecto.

La pregunta en cuestión (como ejemplo) es esta:
[Bootstrap notify incluir notificación en una funcion [duplicada]](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/21153/bootstrap-notify-incluir-notificaci%C3%B3n-en-una-funcion)

Y el mensaje en la zona inferior a traducir sería el siguiente:

```
marcada como duplicada por... <--- que debería ir en Mayúsculas el inicio.
This question was marked as an exact duplicate of an existing question.
```

Por si sirve de algo.

Comment: A tema informativo. He revisado en Transifex y la frase está correctamente traducida.

Comment: @MiquelColl a que te refieres con _está correctamente traducida_ ¿Que debería verse en Español? _PD.: Enhorabuena por lo de moderador!_

Comment: Me refiero a que en la herramienta de traducción esa frase ya está traducida y aceptada, pero como bien dices sigue sin aparecer traducida en el sitio. El comentario es básicamente para descartar que sea un tema de Transifex y tiene mas bien pinta a: 1. Está hardcoded en BBDD. 2. Las frases no se actualizan si la pregunta se marcó como duplicada antes de traducir esa frase. - P.D.: :D

Comment: @MiquelColl gracias por la aclaración!

Comment: Aclaro porque veo que hay algo de confusión. Para que una traducción de Transifex sea visible en el sitio son necesarios tres pasos: 1) la frase debe ser marcada como revisada en Transifex, 2) un empleado de Stack (servidor, por ejemplo) debe importar las traducciones a la base de datos (es un clic, pero hay que hacerlo a mano), y 3) el código debe pasar a producción. En ese orden.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

La frase estaba traducida en Transifex pero **no** estaba marcada como revisada. Lo acabo de hacer, la traducción debería verse tras la próxima compilación.